# Repeat element found once in page multiple times in CSV file (forum post parsing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS4 on Python 2.7.13 to parse forum posts from a website that I will ultimately put in a CSV file.  My issue is that only the first post in the thread has data on the title of the thread, but I want to the title of the post to appear in each line of the CSV file I am creating of the forum posts.  Each line should have the post title, the post's author, the post date and time, and the post's content.  When I search for author, date/time, and content, I receive as many results as there are in the page, so 19 in this instance.  So there should be 19 lines in the CSV file.  However, I only receive one line of output in the CSV, and I presume this is because BS4 can only find one instance of an "h4" tag with attribute "post-name" whereas the other three pieces of data are found multiple times.

Can I write code where the first instance of the title is repeated for all the posts in the page and put into the CSV document?  I have tried to use if/else syntax, but I haven't found a way to tell BS4 that if it cannot find the title for a subsequent post, it should just include the initial soup.title.

I really appreciate your help as I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere.  Maybe I am searching for the wrong thing.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3513/t/20015349?pi21953=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

one = soup.findAll("h4", attrs={"post-name"})
two = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"internal-link view-user-profile"})
three = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"internal-link view-post"})
four = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"post-content user-defined-markup"})

posttitle = []
poster = []
postdateandtime = []
postcontent = []

for post in one:
    text = BeautifulSoup(str(post).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", " ")
    posttitle.append(text.strip())

for post in two:
    text2 = BeautifulSoup(str(post).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", " ")
    poster.append(text2.strip())

for post in three:
    text3 = BeautifulSoup(str(post).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", " ")
    postdateandtime.append(text3.strip())

for post in four:
    text4 = BeautifulSoup(str(post).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", " ")
    postcontent.append(text4.strip())

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'wb')

writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

writer.writerow(["Post Title", "Poster", "Post Date and Time", "Post Content"])

for posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent in zip(posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent):
writer.writerow([posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent])

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip_longest to fill missing values with the `fillvalue` argument. Just give the last element of posttitle so the last title is used for all missing:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent in izip_longest(posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent, fillvalue=posttitle[-1):
    writer.writerow([posttitle, poster, postdateandtime, postcontent])
```

Comment: I can't tell you how appreciative I am of your help, tayfun!  I have been looking for a solution for days and it was becoming very stressful for me.  Thank you so much for clear and concise solution, my friend.  I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad to be of help @Vlakoulis :)